# Get lat/long from the google mapview

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, location

I need to get the lat/long of the location where user taps on the google map view. Is there a necessity to open GooglePlacePickerViewController for this? I need to achieve this in the GMSMapView which is used to show user current location.

Comment: `GooglePlacePickerViewController ` not requrired. Go through this [Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) and use `mapView:didTapAtCoordinate:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple use Delegate method

First set delegate

```
    self.mapView.delegate = self
```

Then just

```
extension YourViewController:GMSMapViewDelegate {


   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

       // USER TAP ON  coordinate
   }
}
```

Suggestion : Just go through this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-you-can-use-the-google-maps-sdk-with-ios-using-swift-4-a9bba26d9c4d will not take more than 20 min that my promise will conver all the basic stuff. :)

If you need points of view based system. for example if you want what is exact point where user tap according to view X, Y

Then

you can do it like this

```
let points:CGPoint = mapView.projection.point(for:coordinates)
```

Bingo !!

Answer (score 0):

assign delegate like this.

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

And use `GMSMapViewDelegate` to use below method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at Location \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
}
```